# adding a domain name to my digital ocean droplet

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

I have a digital ocean droplet that I have no troubles accessing with the ip address. Now I bought a domain name and I am trying to add the domain name to my droplet.

I've added the NS records to the domain name but when I do a whois I still get to see the standard namespaces. Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

Here you can see where I edited the NS records:

[image]

I am following this guide from the digital ocean website:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-host-name-with-digitalocean

Answer (score 1):

`work-place.be` needs to be pointed at the Digital Ocean nameservers at your domain registrar. Just adding NS records on the DO side doesn't do anything (or I could add your domain to *my* DO records and hijack it).

Right now, the following nameservers are responsible for the domain:

```
ns1.jcrea-dns2.be
ns2.jcrea-dns2.be
```

Comment: I'm sorry but what exactly is my domain registrar? I can't seem to find any option to change the name servers with the login credetentials they game me to login to DirectAdmin

Comment: @Miklo Your registrar is the company you bought the domain from. Whois says yours looks like it's http://www.webcreating.be.